# How to fetch a JSON file to get a row position from a given value or argument

Tags: json, indexing, position, row, indexof

I'm using wget to fetch several dozen JSON files on a daily basis that go like this:

```
 {
 "results":  [
     {
      "id": "ABC789",
      "title": "Apple",
     },
     {
      "id": "XYZ123",
      "title": "Orange",
     }]
 }
```

My goal is to find row's position on each JSON file given a value or set of values (i.e. "In which row XYZ123 is located?"). In previous example ABC789 is in row 1, XYZ123 in row 2 and so on.

As for now I use Google Regine to "quickly" visualize (using the Text Filter option) where the XYZ123 is standing (row 2).

But since it takes a while to do this manually for each file I was wondering if there is a quick and efficient way in one go.

What can I do and how can I fetch and do the request? Thanks in advance! FoF0

Comment: I guess PHP since I'm a little bit familiar with. I'm not a programmer but I am not intimidated by reading or editing it (in a limited way obviously).

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
import json
#assume json_string = your loaded data
data = json.loads(json_string)
mapped_vals = []
for ent in data:
  mapped_vals.append(ent['id'])
```

The order of items in the list will be indexed according to the json data, since the list is a sequenced collection.

In PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
$output = array();
foreach($data as $values){
  $output[] = $values->id;
}
```

Again, the ordered nature of PHP arrays ensure that the output will be ordered as-is with regard to indexes.

Either example could be modified to use a mapped dictionary (python) or an associative array (php) if needs demand.

You could adapt these to functions that take the `id` value as an argument, track how far they are into the array, and when found, break out and return the current index.

Comment: Great! But I don't get how to fetch the file (sorry, I'm not a programmer).

Comment: If you're using wget and directing the output to a file just use `open` in the case of python and `file_get_contents` in the case of php.  While we're on that... which language are you looking for ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry...I some how pressed the Add Comment button before thanking you DeaconDesperado.

Comment: Hi DeaconDesperado! I'm using wget but not using the "-O" option but the "-i" one (I have a URLs.txt file which contains all URLs I want to retrieve)..so after fetching I have a bunch of files which I need to manually analyse one by one ¬¬' I'm not looking for a particular language since I don't know any :P But I have edited over PHP files.

Comment: Look into urllib for python or curl for php.  Both allow you to fetch data from a url inline in the script.

Comment: Perfect DeaconDesperado! I'm going to try curl (python souns to scary for me :P) and I'll post results here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I posted the original question 10 months ago when I knew nothing about Python nor computer programming whatsoever!

**Answer**
But I learned basic Python last December and came up with a solution for not only get the rank order but to insert the results into a MySQL database:

```
import urllib.request
import json

# Make connection and get the content
response = urllib.request.urlopen(http://whatever.com/search?=ids=1212,125,54,454)
content = response.read()

# Decode Json search results to type dict
json_search = json.loads(content.decode("utf8"))

# Get 'results' key-value pairs to a list
search_data_all = []

for i in json_search['results']:
    search_data_all.append(i)

# Prepare MySQL list with ranking order for each id item

ranks_list_to_mysql = []

for i in range(len(search_data_all)):
    d = {}
    d['id'] = search_data_all[i]['id']
    d['rank'] = i + 1
    ranks_list_to_mysql.append(d)
```